# Computing the approximate or exact area of an isosurface

Tags: geometry, surfaces, area, computational-geometry, surface-integrals

The isosurfaces I'm reading about are defined by a constant value *v* in a scalar field. 
The scalar field is defined by placing n vectors in k-space such that

$iso(\vec{x})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_k(x_k-p_{i_k})^2$

So the field value at each point in space is the sum of all squared distances. 
I'm interested to find a function *a(v)* that computes or approximates the area given $iso(\vec{x})=v$ as the isovalue.

Is there maybe a closed form that immediately gives the result? What would be good further reading on that topic? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your isosurface is a sphere, having center at the centroid of the $p_i$ and whose radius $r$ is given by
$$
r^2={v\over n}-{1\over n^2}\sum_{i\ne j}(\vec p_i-\vec p_j)^2.
$$
That follows from the identity
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n(\vec x-\vec p_i)^2=
n\left(\vec x -\sum_{i=1}^n{\vec p_i\over n}\right)^2+
{1\over n}\sum_{i\ne j}{(\vec p_i-\vec p_j)^2}.
$$
Once $r$ is known it is easy to get the area of the sphere.
Notice however that an isosurface exists only if ${v}>{1\over n}\sum_{i\ne j}(\vec p_i-\vec p_j)^2$.

Comment: Do you mean that there is a transformation that makes the different centers $\vec{p_i}$ forming the isosurface in question to correspond to the area of the circle? How do I get there?

Comment: Is there a difference in obtaining the function if the distance is used instead? I.e. $iso(\vec{x})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\vec{x}-\vec{p_i}|$

Comment: I meant a (hyper)sphere, not a circle, I've corrected now. At first I misread your question and thought it was a 2D problem, but the answer is substantially the same. If you replace squared distance with distance the answer is much more difficult, I'm afraid.